# python findall null

Tags: python, regex, helper, findall

I'm generating a bot that should receive telegram messages and forward them to another group after applying regex to the received message.

Regex tested in PHP and sites around the web, in theory it should work.

```py
regex = r"⏰ Timeframe M5((\s+(.*)\s+){1,})⏰ Timeframe M15"
text_example = '''⏰ Timeframe M5


04:05 - EURUSD - PUT
05:15 - EURJPY - PUT
06:35 - EURGBP - PUT
07:10 - EURUSD - PUT
08:15 - EURJPY - PUT

⏰ Timeframe M15

06:35 - EURGBP - PUT
07:10 - EURUSD - PUT
08:15 - EURJPY - PUT '''

reg = re.findall(regex, example_text)
print(reg)
```

return me
`[ ]`

I've run out of attempts..

I've used regex in other situations and had no problems, in this one I don't know why it works

Comment: I've pasted your regex and example input in https://regex101.com and it doesn't work.

Comment: Which part do you expect to be captured by the capturing-group?

Comment: @Samathingamajig https://regex101.com/r/gvulvK/3

Comment: @M.Spiller everything between Timeframe M5 and ⏰ Timeframe M15

Comment: The difference between the regex behind https://regex101.com/r/gvulvK/3 and the code you have pasted above is the _multiline_ mode. Try changing your call to `findall` to `re.findall(regex, example_text, re.MULTILINE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern does not work for the example data because you are repeating 1 or more leading AND trailing whitespace characters after `.*`. This will not match if you have 2 consecutive lines without for example extra spaces at the end that you do seem to have in this regex example https://regex101.com/r/gvulvK/3

Note that the name of the initial variable is `text_example`

What you might do is match the start and the end of the pattern, and in between match all lines that do not start with for example the ⏰

```
⏰ Timeframe M5\s*((?:\n(?!⏰).*)+)\n⏰ Timeframe M15\b
```

See this [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/sdOYrE/1) and this [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Cz7zE/1)

```
import re

regex = r"⏰ Timeframe M5\s*((?:\n(?!⏰).*)+)\n⏰ Timeframe M15\b"
text_example = '''⏰ Timeframe M5


04:05 - EURUSD - PUT
05:15 - EURJPY - PUT
06:35 - EURGBP - PUT
07:10 - EURUSD - PUT
08:15 - EURJPY - PUT

⏰ Timeframe M15

06:35 - EURGBP - PUT
07:10 - EURUSD - PUT
08:15 - EURJPY - PUT '''

reg = re.findall(regex, text_example)
print(reg)
```

Output

```
['\n04:05 - EURUSD - PUT\n05:15 - EURJPY - PUT\n06:35 - EURGBP - PUT\n07:10 - EURUSD - PUT\n08:15 - EURJPY - PUT\n']
```

Answer (score -1):

If you slightly change your regex and also run it in dot all mode, it should work:

```py
regex = r'⏰ Timeframe M5.*?⏰ Timeframe M15'
matches = re.findall(regex, text_example, flags=re.S)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
⏰ Timeframe M5


04:05 - EURUSD - PUT
05:15 - EURJPY - PUT
06:35 - EURGBP - PUT
07:10 - EURUSD - PUT
08:15 - EURJPY - PUT

⏰ Timeframe M15
```

Comment: no feedback has worked yet